# Clone Failed SageMaker MLOps Project Using Third-party Git Repos

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to use MLOps template for model building, training, and deployment with third-party Git repositories using CodePipeline.

I created the project successfully using the template and all the seed code is available in the GitHub repos I specified. But when I try to clone the repo to get the conetents of the repos to studio environment, I am getting the below error
[Clone Failed - Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLgTH.png)

`Clone failed Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/conda/envs/studio/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab_git/git.py", line 144, in execute code, output, error = await current_loop.run_in_executor( File "/opt/conda/envs/studio/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/opt/conda/envs/studio/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab_git/git.py", line 110, in call_subprocess process = subprocess.Popen( File "/opt/conda/envs/studio/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__ self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, File "/opt/conda/envs/studio/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sagemaker-user/home/sagemaker-user/cat-ml-test-1-p-mtd5ofsbdgva/sagemaker-p-mtd5ofsbdgva-modeldeploy'`

I see that the local path that has been specified in

`No such file or directory: '/home/sagemaker-user/home/sagemaker-user/cat-ml-test-1-p-mtd5ofsbdgva/sagemaker-p-mtd5ofsbdgva-modeldeploy'`

does not sound quite right. But there's is no option to change the local path by myself also.

How can I solve this?